# Some product categories keep loading without results

Tags: magento-1.8, tierprice

I am uncertain what is happening over here, but it is realy bugging me.
We installed the module Tierprices from MagPleasure (version 1.2.2) on our website, but it seems to load some of our product categories endless.

We disabled and enabled all third party modules to see if this works.
But the results remain the same.
This is what we have tried to make it work:
1. Contacted MagPleasure about this bug (they fixed a lot but couldn't find the issue about this one).
2. Disabled all modules one by one via app/etc/all xml files.
3. Disabled all modules via database.
4. Edited a couple of errors in the log (nothing to worry about and nothing had to do anything with the tierprices).
5. We even changed template to default.

But all for naught. 
I hope someone knows anything about this bug/error (nothing specific is reported in the logs) and would mind sharing their experience.
If I find out about anything I will ofcourse report back.
Thanks for the help.

This is one of our endless loading pages: [www.dekabelexpert.nl/testlocation/utp-stp-sftp/patchkabels.html](http://www.dekabelexpert.nl/testlocation/utp-stp-sftp/patchkabels.html)

Comment: Can you show output of `n98-magerun dev:module:rewrite:list`? How did you determine that it loops and what does it loop on?

Comment: To answer your question I uploaded a .txt file to my other server. Else it would be to long for a page here. Please check [here for text file](http://max-webdesign.com/list.txt)